# jQuery on(): strange behaviour

Tags: jquery

This code works on my site:

```
$(function(){
    $('.link-follow-stop').on('click', function(event){
        console.log('|||');             
        return false;
    });
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.link-follow-stop', function(event){
        console.log('|||');

        return false;
    });
});
```

I see no errors when running the second code sample on my site, but the `console.log` call does not fire when I click the `.link-follow-stop` link.

I tried running the second code sample at jsFiddle and it worked like I was expected. What can be wrong?

Link with class 'link-follow-stop' is static (I mean not dynamic).

Comment: It the elements are not inserted dynamically, why do you care? You should stick with the first one.

Comment: If the you tried the second code, ran it on jsfiddle, and it worked as expected, what's the issue?

Comment: I think he's saying it doesn't work on his site, but it works at jsfiddle.

Comment: You need to show an example that *doesn't* work. Otherwise it's pretty hard to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Are there any iframes involved with your site?

Comment: This code doesn't works on my page, so, I want to understand why? And I want to fix this.

Comment: check your code for $(document).off('click'... If you find it, then you'll want to namespace your events or bind it to a different element.  while there are cases where you want to bind to document, most of the time you don't need to.

Comment: @Swordfish0321, console.log('|||') in second code doesn't fire.

Comment: @Asad, no they aren't. There are no iframes at that page where I test a code.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, you are quite right!

Comment: Can you provide the address of the page , so that we can see

Comment: @Alice, no, I can't. It is on localhost.

Comment: @DMoses, As I remember I didn't use "$(document).off('click'"... maybe there are another pitfalls in using on()?

Comment: Guys, thanks for participation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a click handler on an element that contains `.link-follow-stop` and it uses `e.stopPropagation()`, this will prevent the event from bubbling up to `document`. The second form of `.on()` depends on the event bubbling up to the element that that handler is bound to; it then checks whether the actual target of the event matches the selector.

The following demonstrates this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Click here
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".inner", function() {
        alert("inner");
    });
    $(".outer").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("outer");
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QHz4b/3/)

When you delegate with `.on()` you should bind the handler to the most specific static element(s) that contains the dynamic element. This minimizes the risk that another handler will interfere and prevent bubbling.

Comment: I replaced $(document) on $('.my-outer-link-container') and second code works fine. Thanks! I think I can check your answer as accepted.